# Excel: Replace INDIRECT() to dynamically refer to worksheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet with lots of INDIRECT() functions to pull data from other sheets in the same workbook. Something like

```
=INDIRECT(SheetName&"!A1")
```

I've realized that INDIRECT() is a volatile function so it re-calculates every time when any change is made in any workbook. This makes Excel very slow especially when there are several workbooks opened.

Is there any other function that could replace INDIRECT() to lookup with dynamic sheet name?

Comment: have you considered turning off automatic calculation?

Comment: did you tried `CHOOSE` function?

Comment: CHOOSE is a good replacement as long as you only have a small number of worksheets to choose from: its a dynamic choice between a fixed set of alternatives.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams Thanks Charles, but I'm not sure how it works with different worksheets. Should I just put different ranges in the arguments?
 Could you please write an example?

Comment: Note that the slowness isn't caused just by the Volatile functions recalculating, but also by any functions (volatile or otherwise) *downstream* of those Volatile functions in the calculation chain. Basically, any function downstream of a volatile function effectively becomes a volatile function itself. You might only have *one* volatile function in your workbook, but if that function ultimately feeds large portions of your workbook, then pretty much the entire workbook will recalculate any time you do anything, because of that single volatile function.

Comment: Lisa: see the example I link to in my answer. But effectively you define each of your data ranges as named ranges (e.g. "Forecast", "Budget", "Historic") and then use a lookup table to convert those text strings into a number (1, 2, 3) and return the number to a cell (say A2). And then you feed the resulting number to a CHOOSE function `=CHOOSE(A2, Forecast, Budget, Historic)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lisa: You can use CHOOSE in association with a lookup table to replace INDIRECT. See the screenshot in my answer to this question: [Excel Vlookup with cell reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47227126/excel-vlookup-with-cell-reference/47229599#47229599)

Also, check out my answer at [Excel tables vs plain data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47173491/excel-tables-vs-plain-data/47174723#47174723) where I give a bit of info on how you can address the root cause of your slow spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

- Turn off automatic calculations (strongly not advisable)
- Build a UDF function, that is non-volatile by default:

---

```
Public Function IndirectNotVolatile(sheetName As String, sheetRange As Range) as Variant
    Set IndirectNotVolatile = Worksheets(sheetName).Range(sheetRange.Address)
End Function
```

Comment: its is not true that every built-in function in Excel is volatile: there are only a few - notably INDIRECT and OFFSET besides the obvious RAND etc

Comment: @CharlesWilliams - true, I was thinking about something else.

Comment: Shouldn't this be **Set** IndirectNotVolatile = Worksheets(sheetName).Range(sheetRange.Address)

Comment: @jeeped - I tested it some hours ago, it was working quite ok without the `Set`.

Comment: Setting calculation to manual is very bad advice in my opinion. It addresses the symptoms of a slow spreadsheet, without doing anything about the causes. And it's dangerous: if it's the first spreadsheet you open, then any other spreadsheets you open for the rest of your session will also have manual calc mode applied, without users even knowing it.

Comment: @jeffreyweir - it is dangerous indeed. I have seen a lot of problems because of it. But it is a way to solve it, if you know what you are doing.

Comment: Setting calc to manual to avoid Excel calculating slowly is a code smell, and doesn't solve anything. It simply masks the symptoms of a poorly designed spreadsheet and suboptimal formula choices.  I’ve rewired spreadsheets that users had to run in manual calc mode so that recalculation time drops from minutes to milliseconds and file size drops from hundreds of megabytes to a tiny fraction of that. Meaning they can switch back to auto, and those files stop being ticking time bombs. If you truly know what you are doing, then manual calc mode is the one thing you don't do.

Comment: The only time I switch to Manual Calc Mode is at the start of *some* VBA routines, and I immediately switch back to auto at the end. And even then, most of the time you don't even need to do that if your spreadsheet follows the excellent advice you'll find at Charles Williams' article here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/excel-tips-for-optimizing-performance-obstructions

Comment: @jeffreyweir - true, switching to manual is dangerous indeed - no doubt about it. But if you do not have the time to redesign the whole sheet, it is a way to have some work done. Now it is a philosophic, time management question - should I redesign something that would take me about 10 hours of time to make sure that it is well built or should I turn off caclulations and simply do my job in 10 minutes and forget about it.

Comment: Sure...turn calculations off and *forget* about it. That's my point right here. One day you will. Or someone else will. Heck, they might not even know that such a thing as Manual Calc Mode even exists. And someone will use the output of the model - or some other completely unrelated model they just happenned to open later on in the day -  to make some important decision. And it might well be wrong.  Formulas are code. If it takes hours...or even days...to work out how to refactor badly written, poorly executing code, it is worth it: you learn how to write better code. You become a better coder

Comment: Put it this way: why would you ever want to advise a user to do this, when I offer a very simple alternative in my answer that *completely sidesteps* the danger?

Comment: @jeffreyweir - true, refactoring and redesigning is a must, when it is your responsibility. But what if you your job is just to enter data for 5 minutes in a poorly designed Excel sheet twice per year? You may follow up with the colleagues that it is badly written & that's it.

Comment: I don't see the point of your comment. Refactoring advice is *precisely* what the OP is asking for here.

Comment: Not to make too fine a point of things but your code works for the OP's simple example formula because the example is asking for the cell's value and you are returning the default property (e.g. the .Value) of the range object. If IndirectNotVolatile was used to define the lookup range of a VLOOKUP (which INDIRECT is commonly asked to do), the .Value is insufficient; a Range Object must be returned which the worksheet INDIRECT actually does. If you **Set** the UDF to the Range Object, both situations are satisfied.

Comment: @Jeeped - true, fixed.

Comment: @Vityata, I have just tried the function you proposed as I have 72K indirect formulas in a workbook.  I changed it slightly so that the worksheet name was provided by the named range in the given cell, however it was much much slower than the normal INDRIECT() method.  This was the function i used:

`Public Function IndirectNotVolatile(sheetRange As String) As Variant
Set IndirectNotVolatile = Worksheets(range(sheetRange).Worksheet.name).range(range(sheetRange).Address)
End Function`

PS not putting this as an answer as it runs much slower - perhaps my changes are the problem?