# Alternative to Excel's INDIRECT function that references another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-indirect

In my workbook, I have multiple (15+) sheets, each with 8+ cells that use the INDIRECT function. All the usage of this function is just to reference another sheet in the workbook. This sheet, Data, has multiple rows, each row representing a dataset

Example,

one sheet needs *'Data'!B2*, *'Data'!C2*, *'Data'!F2*, *'Data'!H2*, *'Data'!J2*, etc (there's about 8 of these). So what I do is I have a cells with "Data" and "2" and use INDIRECT to create these formulas. That way, I could easily change the row (2 to say 5) and also change the sheet source (there is another sheet just like Data that I want to work with). I don't want to manually change the formulas on each sheet, it's too tedious.

So as you can see, about 15+ sheets each with 8+ INDIRECT formulas make calculations very very slow.

Is there an alternative I could use that's faster?

[Note: I am aware of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47459948/excel-replace-indirect-to-dynamically-refer-to-worksheets) but 1. the answer doesn't make complete sense to me and 2. a lookup table is not dynamic enough (i.e. sheet names change frequently and the number of 'Data' sheets in a lot)

**EDIT**
I have revisited this sheet and realized that I have multiple array formulas which might also be contributing to calculations speed.

Comment: 15*8 indirect based formulas doesn't seem like a deal breaker. How slow is slow and what else is going on size wize/computationally in the workbook?

Comment: @QHarr slow as in 10-12 mins whenever it calculates, which might not be much in the grand scheme of things but with the work I'm doing, anything more than 3 minutes of calculating is inefficient.  it's about a 2.5mb workbook... no references to any other workbook... plus, I working on a i3 with 2 cores so I don't have my CPU to spare

Comment: I would definitely agree that is very slow. The size also isn't disturbing. I am just perplexed at the performance for what seems like a small number of formulas. Are they nested?

Comment: If the need is to have the sheet name variable too, then there is no way around `INDIRECT` or VBA. Else `=INDEX(Data!$1:$1048576,2,3)` will get `Data!C2` where both, row and column, may be variable.

Comment: I agree with @QHarr that having a handful of `INDIRECT` formulas in your sheet probably isn't (entirely) the root cause of your formula taking several minutes to recalculate. The only time I've found `INDIRECT` unavoidable is if the sheet name itself is dynamic, but it doesn't sound like that is what is going on here. Sounds like you always refer to the `Data` sheet so `INDIRECT` could be avoided by using `INDEX` most likely. Sounds like if you want this issue solved, you'll have to edit the question to provide us more details about your spreadsheet.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 - that could be added as an answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47459948/excel-replace-indirect-to-dynamically-refer-to-worksheets so that this one could be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @AxelRichter - that could be added as an answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47459948/excel-replace-indirect-to-dynamically-refer-to-worksheets to that this one could be closed as a duplicate. Pity we can't address two commentators in a single comment!

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 does your INDEX solution look like what Axel Richter suggests in his comment?

Comment: @Oneiros Yes, that may solve this question (exactly as the question is worded), but again this might not actually be the root of your problem with the long spreadsheet recalculation times. This is why I suggested providing more details about your spreadsheet.

Comment: As an extension of Axel's comment, https://stackoverflow.com/a/47189998/3038828 discusses the same index method if trying to get an array without volatility.  Helped me, maybe it'll help others.